# javascript cannot set value inside ajax

Tags: javascript

I have a question about $.ajax in javascript:

If I have a function like this:

```
var jQueryFunction = function()
{
   var array = new Array();       
   ...

   $.ajax ({
       type: "GET",
       async: false,
       url: TPS_URL_1,
       dataType: "jsonp",
       jsonp: "callback",
       jsonpCallback: "tpsHandler",
       success: function(json)
       {
          array[0] = 1;
          array[1] = 2;
       }
   });

}
```

After that when I check array value, it isn't set by anything and still null.

However I do like this:

```
var jQueryFunction = function()
{
   var array = new Array(); 
       array[0] = 1;
       array[1] = 2;      
   ...

   $.ajax ({
       ...

   });

}
```

It works fine.

So why I cannot set value for array inside $.ajax?

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, maybe when you check the array the callback hasn't been called yet

Comment: Show your complete `ajax` function, it's not clear what you are trying to do and what is going on.

Comment: You can set your array inside the AJAX call.  What's important is when you set the value and when you try to access the value.  Which you haven't explicitly shown in your example.  Can you provide a complete *working* example which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The line `$.ajax({...})` is the equivalent of

```
var obj = {...};
$.ajax(obj);
```

The statement `array[0] = 1` is not something that can be placed inside a object declaration like that (ie the code `var obj = {array[0]=1}` is not valid), thus the code you've posted is invalid (it throws a SyntaxError)

If you want to set these array elements AFTER the ajax returns, you should use the success callback:

```
$.ajax({url: ...,
    success: function(returnData) {
        array[0] = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes. array[0] = 1 is in success:function(returnData){array[0] = 1}, but it doesn't work

Comment: Bear in mind that ajax is asynchronous. Have you verified that the ajax call has actually returned before checking array values? Are you sure your ajax call is actually succeeding?

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

Simple:

```
var setup = {
    url         :   'index.php',
    dataType    :   "json",
    type        :   "post",
    data        :   {
        time        :   "now"
    },
    success     :   function(response)
    {
        console.log( response ) ;
    }
};
$.ajax( setup );
```

API( [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) ):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url         :   'index.php',
    dataType    :   "json",
    type        :   "post",
    success     :   function(response)
    {
        console.log( response ) ;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    data:{
        time    :   "now"
    }
});
```